# How to remove fullCalendar time table from week view - Angular

Tags: css, angular, fullcalendar

I'm working in Angular project and I use `fullcalendar` component.

My issue is that I want to remove the table that contains the time in the view week.

I tried to use CSS but it doesn't hide the border table:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the dayGridWeek (or dayGridDay) view would be suitable for your purposes. This creates a vertical list of events but without a time grid. No need to customise the CSS or anything like that.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view-demo for a demo, and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view for documentation.